# How can I use a camcorder as webcam on USB mode?

Tags: webcam, camera

We have a Sony Handycam DCR-SX15. We want to use the camcorder as a webcam to live stream with it. Computer on Ubuntu and other operation systems list it as a storage device. I searched on forums but topics are old and softwares are out of date. Only USB cable option, no analog or firmware.

Comment: What you need to verify is whether your Sony Handycam (specific model) supports USB mode. My limited experience says that it might not.

Answer (score 2):

Well I've been rummaging around and I can't find anything that suggests you can use the DCR-SX15 as a webcam through USB. If you can provide something to the contrary, I'll be quiet.

Why are you against analogue? You can pick up an AverMedia DVD EZMaker for ~£30 and it should show up as a V4L device out the box. You can pipe that through something like [Webcam Studio](http://code.google.com/p/webcamstudio/downloads/list) and your computer will treat it like a real webcam. You might not even need that last step.